# Can Akka or the Actor model give more processing power to an app?

Tags: multithreading, akka, actor

I’m trying to get my head around why use Akka/Actor model. Suppose a machine has allocated to my **stateless** application only 2 threads and I have two Actors (Actor1 & Actor2). When a requests comes to **Actor1** it pushes it onto **Actor2**, freeing up **Actor1** to serve more requests. In this case at least 1 thread is always occupied, either by **Actor1** or **Actor2**.

Why shouldn’t I just serve requests coming into the **Actor1** onto the **Actor2** in a single thread (blocking way) which will also use 1 thread and the benefit of using this code would be

1. easier to debug the code this way for a stateless application because it's running in a single thread.
2. The second thread can serve other requests.
3. the processing time of the full request might be quicker because to invoke say DAO from Service is just a function call whereas in Akka's case I will be delegating from Actor1 to Actor2 and Akka will be doing some thread management magic under the hood which means more code to execute and slower execution.
4. I will be writing less code to return responses for HTTP requests because it's blocked and in a single thread and having a return statement will cascade the response back to the user. Whereas in Akka I will passing the request context around (In Sprays-can case) and will be invoking `complete {}` way deep in the application layer when the request is actually complete. Or I will be using some special Akka pattern to serve Response for every request. ***Sounds like I will be writing to be too much code here***
5. Backpressure will only be required at the Client request end point.

Can Akka/Actor model help me gain more out of a machine which only offers 1 or 2 threads to my application ?